# "I am in my twenties" - is a natural sentence?

Tags: phrase-request

If I don't want to specify the exact age, can I say "I am in my twenties (or 30s, 40s)", or I should add words like 'of age' or others?

Comment: It's also written as **"I'm in my 20s"** The word "twentieth" is an ordinal number, it's precise and specific usually used for calendar dates such as "The party is scheduled for the 20th of March"

Comment: @Mari-LouA. I edited it based on your note. Thank you.

Comment: My comment was to complement James K's answer. You shouldn't really change the content of your question when someone has posted an answer. Although his answer hasn't been invalidated by the edit so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom is "I'm in my twenties". You can modify with "early", "mid" or "late" if you wish. The word "age" isn't required, but may be understood by context.

<sub>By way of contrast, a friend told me that he had "reached 100", which I correctly understood to mean that he had "done 100 parkruns". and wasn't 100 years old - I knew this because I know him to be less than 80, and he was handing out cake at the finish line of a parkrun, so there was no ambiguity.</sub>

For higher ages: "thirties", "forties" etc.  For younger: "teens", but less than 13, you'd just say "a child".